# Cassandra - delete all rows stored in a primary key value fast?

Tags: cassandra

I am creating a table which will contain a lot (we are talking million if not billion) of data stored by a primary key which will be a year stored as int.
We are doing this because we wish to be able to execute simple purge.

table look like this:

```
TABLE data (
 year int,
 fulldate date,
 ref1 text,
 ref2 text,
 data blob,
 PRIMARY KEY ((year), fulldate, ref1, ref2)
);
```

In the future, we plan to drop all the data of a year and will not add any more data to this particular year.

Can we delete all the data stored by a primary key value in an efficient way? Like doing something similar to a drop?

I haven't seen anything about such a thing in the doc, but I am new to Cassandra so maybe there is an internal optimization done or something?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete all data of a partition key with only one query.

Just Specify the partition key year when deleting.

```
DELETE from data WHERE year = 2017;
```

And it is efficient Because it only create a single tombstone for that partition value.

Comment: Nice thanks, I knew the query but I wasn't sure about it's optimization :D